# Audit fail: An answer that links to another answer of the same question is considered "high-quality"

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I disliked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49369812/8413636) so much that *after* I failed the audit, I went and downvoted it.  Am I wrong here?

This answer is a link to another answer... of the same question.

I should note that I read the comments on the answer, and they fail to clarify for me what value this answer adds.

Comment: That makes more sense. The app pointed me to the wrong answer when I clicked the link. I agree with you. I think this is a case where the system is assuming high votes = good answer. In all fairness, that's *usually* a fair assumption.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the answer that the answer is linking to was updated after the fact. It didn't have the new keyword, and added it on the 3rd. The answer being discussed here had the updated method before the accepted answer. At least it seems that way from looking over the edits.

Comment: Hmm, so it sounds like originally it was...maybe not a great answer, but maybe not something I would have downvoted.  (Although I don't think so).  In any event, when this happens (a 'faulty audit' question), should I just move on with my life, flag it, or what?

Comment: Well you've already down voted it so it's no longer eligible to be used as an audit. In general, posting on Meta like you've already done is how to dispute an audit.

Comment: I believe it isn't linking to the question-text itself, and perhaps not even the updated question-title - but to the *comments* under the question.

Comment: Hi, all I updated my accepted answer to include the additional information. The password change happened 18 months after my initial answer hence why I did not include it there initially. I added it because I thought the other answer was poor IMHO (as discussed here) and I commented under that answer to that effect. Additionally other information had changed also, so my answer was out of date, and I brought it up to date. Is there a better way I should have done this? Don't want to be accused of stealing another answer (though as others have pointed out it was itself stolen)!

Comment: @BarryPollard - You understand it's not YOUR answer I was complaining about?  The answer I was complaining about has been removed.  I think you understand that, just making sure...

Comment: I do. Was responding to @Carcigenicate's comment.

Comment: Has nobody noticed that the question is off topic? It's about a browser quirk that doesn't have anything to do with programming...

Comment: @Will I'm not sold. It's about a browser quirk that is (hopefully) *only* of interest to programmers.

Comment: @Flexo it's specifically about how to get a browser to ignore a bad cert. That's not programming related at all. It might be *slightly* related to website hosting, which is still not on topic for SO. I know, I'm doing my best lately to let borderline stuff be, but this isn't anywhere near the border. It's completely off topic. Stop being so flex, yo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I completely agree with you. This answer should be deleted.

Why? Well primarily because it is clearly NAA (Not An Answer). Let's examine the non-link content of the answer:

> The new keyword is 'thisisunsafe'

Now let's look at the question:

> My question: does this solution work only for specific site or Chrome will not throw certificate/HSTS errors for all other sites after I've used this keyword?

Consulting the [holy texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712), we find that:

> if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer

But I don’t see one here, not even a partial one. All I see is tangential commentary, and a tangerine is not an apple.

---

Now that we've established that, we can discuss whether the content provided is useful. Judging from the number of upvotes, I'd say many people felt that it was.

Useful content is nice to keep around, and so this information should be edited into some other post. **But wait**, *it already has been*, the question title includes this information, and actually had it five days before the non-answer was written.

The information has also been edited into the accepted answer (after the fact), and is mentioned in numerous comments on the question. I can think of no possible reason to keep the redundant non-answer around any longer.

I've flagged it for moderator attention saying such, hopefully it will be gone shortly.

Comment: That's not how Not an Answer is defined: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712). Yes, this is unintuitive. Yes, we've been arguing with SO about how unintuitive it is for years. Taking a pragmatic view, though, it's *clearly* relevant information to readers.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's "relevant" only in the same sense that quoting back a paragraph of the question with no further commentary would be "relevant". It repeats information that's already in the question and does nothing more. I agree that this answer doesn't meet the *extremely narrow* definition that we're often asked to apply to "Not an answer", but that's the letter-of-the-law view; the "pragmatic" view, as far as I'm concerned, is that this answer adds zero information to the page, is simply confusing to any new reader who encounters it, and therefore ought not to exist any more.

Comment: @jpmc26 I’ve seen that post before, and still feel this answer doesn’t fit any category other than orange. Just because you add useful information to a post doesn’t make it an answer. That information also has to be relevant. Where is the “honest attempt to answer the question” Shog requires, cause I’m not seeing any.

Comment: @River we probably all feel like that, the NAA flag is the most aggravating in the site. The number if times I've seen a question say "I can't do X, because" and then a rapid answer says "Maybe do X"... I mash the mouse button really hard when downvoting and pretend it makes a difference.

Comment: @Gimby that’s still an attempt to solve the problem at hand, this does nothing of the sort.

Comment: Note, that another holy text also states: Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This *includes answers* that are: exact duplicates of other answers [... or] not even a partial answer to the actual question.

Comment: On the basis of the votes here and the fact that the question asks "does this apply to a specific site or all sites?", which that clearly doesn't address I've deleted the answer.

Comment: @jpmc26  The only ones who debate "what particular pieces of trash" belong here are people like you. Mods are people, and with sufficient information, will happily delete nonsequitr answers from any question.  I'm not sure why you people are so fixated on the pedantic elements of the guideline, there are many other ambiguous clauses that mods decide to make non pedantic decisions with because it helps the quality of the site.   In fact that is a style of thinking you could benefit from, think "does taking action here hurt or benefit site quality" instead of "does it fit exact wording"

Comment: @Flexo uh, the question's off topic. You might want to close that as well...

Comment: @snb You need to spend more time on Meta.  Mods not deleting obvious trash flagged as NAA is the very reason why the definition and wording have been [so heavily debated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) for years.